# sharing android application content on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

how can I allow users to share the data(text data) they have saved in android app on their facebook wall through a share button within the app. I am not sure if I should use facebook android sdk device or share-intent. I will be thankful if someone could provide me with some information on this or tell me about any tutorials related to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not share the text on facebook wall using intent in android. For to achieve this you need to use facebook sdk. Using intent you can share the text on email, twitter and can share the photo on facebook.

I used intent earlier to send text on facebook its was not working earlier.

As per the Facebook's Platform Policies, We cannot pre-fill the share dialog using Intent.EXTRA_TEXT. It is usually thought to be a bug, but as per a Bug Report filed here and also, here, Facebook clearly mentions that this is not the case (it's not a bug).

I found that we cannot add a caption to a photo we are uploading using Intents. The only way we can do it, is integrating the **Facebook SDK** in your App then photo with text caption will be shared on facebook wall.

To get started for facebbok sdk in android:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you reply. Actually I have been looking at facebook android sdk tutorial but it only allows to share the post user writes, i want user to share the content they have already saved in app, can you direct me towards steps of doing so?

Comment: @user1952097 I shared my knowledge what should you use to share text on facebook. So to learn the facebook sdk use google and accept answer if its useful post for you.

Comment: Edit-Thanks for this, I just want to ask now, does facebook android sdk allow user to not only post a message they write within status bar but also get data from the app which they have already saved in and share that data on facebook? Thanks

Comment: I tried to share the text and photo on wall. Please accept this answer if if its useful for you.